# Development mode for node.js passport google strategy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to node.js and am using passport for authentication with the GoogleStrategy.  So far anytime I have to restart the server I have to go through the entire login process manually and am wondering if there's a way to "disable" the google authentication, just simply returning a user from my backend (mongodb)?

I'd rather not have to clutter my code with IF statements to simulate a "Development mode".

Thanks,

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually, I've scrapped most of it and figured I'd ask here.  The things I've tried would be to flip between a Local strategy with a hardcoded username/password when in development and the Google strategy although this just feels wrong.  In looking through the passport docs I didn't see any way to basically put it in "development mode" and have passport always return the same user.

Comment: Phrased in another way.  Is there a way to authenticate a mock user when using the Google Strategy?  A number of the examples I've came across only deal with the Basic/Local/Digest strategies.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to add Sessions support to your application (see "Sessions" part in [Passport Configuration docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/)).

Using persistent session will allow you to preserve your authentication event after you'll restart your server.

If you're using passport.js with express, you should add [`express-session` middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to your application with some persistent session store, e.g.:

- [Redis Store](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis)
- [MongoDB Store](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)